# 403 Access Forbidden Error

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-403

I have two directories, using the first directory of `(/var/www/html)`, my page is displaying perfectly after I include an index.html file. Then I created a second directory `(/home/xsol/website)` and created another index.html file. However, for the second directory, you will see a 403 forbidden error on the page even after I have given a `chmod -r 755` to that file. My httpd.conf file is as below

```
<Directory "/home/xsol/website">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted 
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted    
</Directory>
```

Comment: is your second directory own by apache? and what's in error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `chmod -R 755` on the `/home/xsol` directory and add these settings to your new dir

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
```